# PostgreSQL connections

Tags: postgresql

My postgres connections stay IDLE forever despite making connections closing statements in code. DB gets hung up after a threshold saying FATAL MEMORY ERROR. This prompts a restart when connections gets closed.

How Can I solve this issue at root? Why aren't connections closing?

**code snippet :**

```
try {

    session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

} finally {  
    if (session != null) {  
        session.close();
    }    
}
```

**Hibernate Config file:**

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
<props>
<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">auto</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">on_close</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider">com.myapp.connections.MultiTenantConnectionsProvider </prop>
<prop key="hibernate.multiTenancy">DATABASE</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver">com.myapp.connections.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver </prop>
</props>
</property>
```

Comment: `session.close()` only puts the connections back into the pool. If you want to make the pool close the physical connections after some time, you need to change the configuration of the pool.

Comment: Can you please guide me on how to change the configuration to achieve it?

Comment: You need to check the documentation of the connection pool you are using.

Comment: Don't close database connections, keep them open and reuse them (pooling). Limit the number of database connections.

Comment: Yes @Laurenz. We are trying to use c3p0 for connection pooling and connections are kept open. But after certain duration of activity, database hungs saying FATAL MEMORY ERROR. This prompts a restart.